# What's the correct usage of "hopefully"?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, disjuncts

I said, "Hopefully, I will get better" to a friend and he said that I was using it incorrectly, stating that *[hopefully](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hopefully)* is an adverb meaning "full of hope" that modifies a verb. It sounds right, but I'm pretty sure that this usage of *hopefully* has become prevalent enough to be accepted for this use case. Am I right, is he right, or are we both right?

Comment: Here’s a delightful example of a usage commentator asserting that “hopefully” cannot be used as a sentence modifier. http://web.archive.org/web/20100524153208/http://www.soyouwanna.com/site/syws/wrerrors/wrerrors7.html

Comment: @nohat: LOL at this quote from that commentator (on page 6 of the 7): << Sorry, trekkies: "to boldly go" just ain't right. Most of our grammar is inherited from Latin, and the infinitives in Latin are one-word (e.g., "comprendere," "facire," and "manere"). We don't know why we ended up with two-word infinitives, but we don't think it's fair to go taking liberties with our infinitives just because they seem vulnerable. >> Wow.

Comment: You friend is painfully wrong.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_%28linguistics%29

Comment: In more recent news, [AP changes rules for “hopefully”](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/arts-post/post/ap-changes-rules-for-hopefully-share-your-grammarpeeves/2012/04/17/gIQAEuN7NT_blog.html?wprss=rss_blogsandcolumns).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_(linguistics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunct_%28linguistics%29) has a section about "hopefully".

In the purest sense, your friend is correct, but "hopefully" has been dated as a disjunct back to the 18th century, so I'd say it is prevalent enough to be considered correct.

Comment: I would even go stronger and say that the friend is only correct in the pedantic, I-think-language-should-work-like-this kind of way.  I like this argument from Random House:

`Although some strongly object to its use as a sentence modifier, hopefully  meaning “it is hoped (that)” has been in use since the 1930s and is fully standard in all varieties of speech and writing: "Hopefully, tensions between the two nations will ease".  This use of hopefully  is parallel to that of certainly, curiously, frankly, regrettably,  and other sentence modifiers.`

Comment: There is a special place in my heart for answers that suggest that the pedants are 100s of years out-of-date.

Comment: Blah. This answer is definitely not bold enough. In the purest sense, your friend is *completely incorrect*. This supposed rule never made the slightest bit of sense, and why the pedants singled out *hopefully* for their scorn I'll never know.

Comment: What on earth is 'the purest sense'? The one that perpetuates the etymological fallacy?